Unhandled exception keeps appearing in VS 2022 even when my project isn't running
Something strange starting happening to me.  I keep getting this persistent Unhandled exception that keeps coming back every few seconds.  The strange part is the exception continues to re-appear even after I stop my project from running and just sit in VS IDE.
Anyone else ever experience this?

